# add custom play and pause button to vine iframe video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have following code to play vine video in my web page.

```
<iframe src="https://vine.co/v/OpBWALdg3na/embed/simple" width="600" height="600" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

But it is play video by default.
Can any one help me to know how can I load video in pause state and after that when I click on my custom button It play that video.

Thanks

Comment: Have you thought about using http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp ? It's really easy to use with or without javascript

Comment: Robin but it will not support all type videos like youtube,twitter, keek etc. and also on mobile devices.